# Change servers (Dev, UAT, Prod) for Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4

My application is developed in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework (using a database-first approach). Currently, this entity is pointing to the dev database server. I want to change it to an UAT server for testing and finally production server for deployment.

My question is, is it achievable only by creating a different `.edmx` file for each of the servers always and rebuild it? Or is there an easy way to change it other than creating a new connection (`.edmx` file) every time?

Thanks

Comment: The connection string in your web.config file just needs to change. Also, why have you tagged two versions of Entity Framework?

Comment: no need for different EDMX assuming the schemas are the same. Just change the connection string. You can use config transformations to help you just change the bits of your config file you need to for each environment.